# How to make check all in datagridview?

Tags: vb.net

Hey i'm curently learning vb.net and i want to know how to check in data gridview when all the row will be checked if i have a checkbox outside. And how can i get the data from whe the row checked

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check all you need to setup a loop like this :

```
For Each Rw As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

    DataGridView1.Item(0, Rw.Index).Value = True
    'item(Col.index, Row.index) so you can set value on each cell of the datagrid

Next
```

to uncheck you juste avec to set the line to `false`

To get a value when a row is check, you need to use events. Here an exemple that give you the value of the second column when you check the first one :

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged

   If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then

       MessageBox.Show("Checkbox changed ! The value of the second column is : " & DataGridView1.Item(1, e.RowIndex).Value)

   End If

End Sub
```